# How to Upgrade HTTP Request to Websocket (Autobahn & Twisted Web )

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn, twisted.web

To give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish with Twisted Web and Autobahn websockets: my UI currently sends an initial HTTP GET request with an upgrade to a websocket in the header. Upon reading that in Twisted Web, the connection needs to switch from HTTP to a websocket protocol to pass data back and forth. Note that this websocket upgrade happens on the same port, `port 8000`.

Does anyone know how I can implement what I am trying to do? Thank you so much.

EDIT: updated code for working example. You can find it here: [Payload from POST Request is Cutoff (Twisted Web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960981/payload-from-post-request-is-cutoff-twisted-web)

Here is my code using Twisted Web:

```
class HttpResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.ws_port = None

    print 'resource invoked'
    def render_GET(self, request):

        print 'render invoked'
        if request.getHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Key'):
            # Processing the Key as per RFC 6455
            key = request.getHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Key')
            h = hashlib.sha1(key + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
            request.setHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', base64.b64encode(h.digest()))

            # setting response headers
            request.setHeader('Upgrade', 'websocket')
            request.setHeader('Connection', 'Upgrade')
            request.setResponseCode(101)
            return ''
        else:
            log("Regular HTTP GET request.")
            return "<html><body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'><iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;' src='http://tsa-graphiql.herokuapp.com/'></iframe></body></html>"

    def render_POST(self,request):
        log("POST request")
        request.setResponseCode(200)

    def handle_single_query(self, queryData):
        log("Handle single query data.")
        return


class HttpWsChannel(http.HTTPChannel):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        log('Data received:\n{}'.format(data))
        if data.startswith('GET'):
            # This will invoke the render method of resource provided
            http.HTTPChannel.dataReceived(self, data)
        if data.startswith('POST'):
            http.HTTPChannel.dataReceived(self, data)
        else:
            """
            Pass binary data to websocket class.
            """
            ws_protocol = self.site.ws_factory.protocol(self.site.ws_factory.connection_subscriptions)
            log(ws_protocol)
            #just echo for now
            # self.transport.write(data)


class HttpFactory(Site):
    """
    Factory which takes care of tracking which protocol
    instances or request instances are responsible for which
    named response channels, so incoming messages can be
    routed appropriately.
    """

    def __init__(self, resource):
        http.HTTPFactory.__init__(self)
        self.resource = resource
        self.ws_factory = WsProtocolFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:8000")
        self.ws_factory.protocol = WsProtocol

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        try:
            channel = HttpWsChannel()
            channel.requestFactory = self.requestFactory
            channel.site = self
            return channel
        except Exception as e:
            log("Could not build protocol: {}".format(e))

site = HttpFactory(HttpResource())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, site)
    reactor.run()
```

EDIT 7/8/2017: Here is the new code I am trying below. The websocket messages are received successfully via the `onMessage` method. However the HTTP requests are not working. The current error I am getting on a GET request is:

```
<html>
  <head><title>404 - No Such Resource</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>No Such Resource</h1>
    <p>No such child resource.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Python code

```
from twisted.web.server import (
    Site,
)
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import (
    Resource,
)
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import (
    WebSocketServerProtocol,
    WebSocketServerFactory,
)
from autobahn.twisted.resource import (
    WebSocketResource,
)


class WebSocketProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("WebSocket connection request: {}".format(request))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("onMessage: {}".format(payload))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = WebSocketProtocol
    resource = WebSocketResource(factory)

    root = Resource()
    root.putChild(b"ws", resource)

    site = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, site)

    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading a little bit on Google, I found this website that explains how to upgrade the HTTP connection to a websocket connection via Autobahn Twisted: [Read and Set request headers via Autobahn Twisted](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_httpheaders).

The code that I was able to get to work is shown below!

```
from twisted.web.server import (
    Site,
)
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import (
    Resource,
)
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import (
    WebSocketServerProtocol,
    WebSocketServerFactory,
)
from autobahn.twisted.resource import (
    WebSocketResource,
)


class HttpResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
    return "<html><body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'><iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;' src='http://tsa-graphiql.herokuapp.com/'></iframe></body></html>"


class WebSocketProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        custom_header = {}

        if request.headers['sec-websocket-key']:
            custom_header['sec-websocket-protocol'] = 'graphql-ws'
        return (None, custom_header)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("onMessage: {}".format(payload))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = WebSocketProtocol
    resource = WebSocketResource(factory)

    root = Resource()
    root.putChild("", HttpResource())
    root.putChild(b"ws", ws_resource)

    site = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, site)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `WebSocketResource` to expose a `WebSocketServerFactory` as part of a `Site`.

```
from twisted.web.server import (
    Site,
)
from twisted.web.resource import (
    Resource,
)
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import (
    WebSocketServerProtocol,
    WebSocketServerFactory,
)
from autobahn.twisted.resource import (
    WebSocketResource,
)

class YourAppProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, request):
        ...

    ...

def main():
    factory = WebSocketRendezvousFactory()
    factory.protocol = YourAppProtocol
    resource = WebSocketResource(factory)
    root = Resource()
    root.putChild(b"some-path-segment", resource)
    root.putChild(...)
    site = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
    reactor.run()
```

The problems with truncated request bodies is probably because your upgrade protocol implementation is buggy.  There is no framing applied at the level of `dataReceived` so you can't expect checks like `startswith("GET")` to be reliable.

Using `WebSocketResource` and `Site` gives you the correct HTTP parsing code from Twisted Web and Autobahn while also allowing you to speak WebSocket to a particular URL and regular HTTP to others.

Comment: I don't think this code shows how you can use autobahn websocket on the same port as HTTP. I have implemented this code before and it's not what I was looking for. I believe I may have a working example using Twisted web library

Comment: I have updated the description with a link to a working example, but experiencing an issue where the requests get cutoff. Still looking into this issue further @jean-paul-calderone

Comment: Thank you! I tried your example and I am able to receive the websocket messages. However I get a 404 when performing a GET request stating there is no such resource - no such child resource found.

Comment: Do I have to explicitly define a Resource class with a render_GET method? Also, do I have to specify how the getChild method to route the websocket requests correctly? I am testing with a REST client by the way. Thanks again!

Comment: A 404 when GETing what?

Comment: GET request at http://127.0.0.1:8000. For the websocket I'm using ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws

Comment: This was something I needed, what I noticed though is that messages from the proxied server is not being sent back to the proxied client. Is that something that I should do, like subclass WebSocketServerProtocol and handle it there?